# Disease risk prediction with LSTM in python - input shape problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, prediction

I am new in machine learning using python. I can not figure out how to reshape my dataset to use as an input in an LSTM model which will predict the risk of having a disease in the future. To be more specific, my dataset looks like the below one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FquFV.png)

| PatientID | MeasurementDate | Parameter1 | Parameter2 | HasDisease |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 106 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/2/2021 | 105,9 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/3/2021 | 107 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2/1/2021 | 100 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2/2/2021 | 100,5 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2/3/2021 | 104 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 3/1/2021 | 97 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 3/2/2021 | 97 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3/3/2021 | 97 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 4/1/2021 | 99 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4/2/2021 | 109 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 4/3/2021 | 110 | 0 | 0 |

How should I reshape this one to be used as an input in LSTM and look like  (batch_size, time_steps, seqeuence_len)?
I would like my LSTM model to return something like PatientId :1
Risk score :80%
which means that patient 1 has 80% probability to have the disease after 3 months.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.

I managed to get the expected result by following this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcGf_Uo7NMw&ab_channel=KnowledgeCenter
and adjust it to my dataset.
Batch size as the number of patients
Timesteps as the number of follow-ups
Sequence_len as the number of attributes as inputs.
It ended up as an nD array.

Answer (score 0):

Take the average of each patient.

I assume inputs are Parameter1 and Parameter 2. Therefore your input shape is (num_rows, 1, 2), your input shape for LSTM should be `LSTM(100, input_shape=(1, 124)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to consider this problem as a time-series problem, then you need to have more data for each patient.
one way is to try to train an LSTM model to predict Parameter1 and Parameter2 by using the available data. also, train a simple binary classification model. then the predicted Parameters and the classification model to define the target (HasDisease).